# Best Method To Make Large Graphene Oxide Sheets?

Tags: synthesis, carbon-allotropes

There are so many methods to make graphene oxide now, I'm not exactly experienced enough to know which is ideal. I want to know what the best method is for making large graphene oxide membranes. The goal is to have a surface area of a square meter.

Graphene oxide is usually made by filtration so the two requirements I have are:

- that it can be made by filtration over porous aluminum oxide (for stability in water as revealed here: bit.ly/1HExnui)...well any method really, as long as Al^3+ cations can be incorporated into the graphene oxide in some way
- that the method is known for success with the helium permeation test (as in essentially only water can pass through the graphene oxide).

I've asked a few questions already here on stackexchange and it always feels strange to simply ...demand or extract information. Thank you all.